# How to remove all versions of python except the default version so that Ubuntu doesn't break?

Tags: package-management, python, uninstall

Pretty much as the title suggested, I've got multiple version of python lying around and they are causing a headache. On Windows, I would just delete every instance of python and start over but I've just discovered that I cannot do that on Ubuntu (should've used virtualenv). Short of formatting and starting from scratch, how can I remove every version of python and their libraries except the original ones?

```
whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python
```

Comment: Read `man update-alternatives` You can easily select the `python` version to use

Comment: As I said in my answer below, the issue wasn't with python itself but one of the libraries that I had installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up, just reinstalled Ubuntu. For anyone wondering, this is what the output of a fresh Ubuntu install should be:

```
whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8
```

Seems like it is the same, so most likely my problem wasn't with python but one of the libraries or what not. Being extra careful with `virtual environments` from now on.